# Unable to install/remove any package on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

When i tried to install curl or any other package on VPS i got the following error:

```
    root@vs3946:/var/www# apt-get install anypackage

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up fuse-utils (2.8.1-1.1ubuntu3.1) ...
mknod: `fuse-': Operation not permitted
makedev fuse c 10 229 root root 0660: failed
chgrp: cannot access `/dev/fuse': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing fuse-utils (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fuse-utils
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@vs3946:/var/www#
```

How can i resolve this problem ? I don't wanna reinstall ubuntu, because, i have a live website on this VPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a broken fuse package which you can't install due to VPS limitations.

I would try to remove the fuse-utils package and then install the "anypackage".

Try:

```
apt-get remove fuse-utils
apt-get -f install
apt-get install anypackage
```

Either as root or use sudo in front of each command.